# Cannot allocate memory

Tags: python, python-3.x

При попытке сконвертировать PDF в PNG (код запущен на VDS) выдает такую ошибку:

> OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Ошибка срабатывает в моменте if..:

```
    if subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, encoding='utf-8'):
        print('Конвертация PDF в PNG - УСПЕХ!')
        return True
    else:
        print('Конвертация PDF в PNG - ПРОВАЛ!')
        return False
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Дополнение:

1. Реализовал файл подкачки (добавил 4ГБ)
2. Запустил - ошибки нет дает, но не конвертирует.
3. Решил вручную запустить команду, которую передаю в параметр:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -o /home/PROJ_FOLD/APP_FOLD/static/cloud/convert/user3363/pdf5/covers/slide-%02d.png -r96 /home/PROJ_FOLD/APP_FOLD/static/cloud/convert/user3363/pdf5/5.pdf
```

Выдало такое:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /ioerror in --run--
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   (    )
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   run   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   run   run   false   1   %stopped_push   2046   1   3   %oparray_pop   run
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:968/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
```

Comment: А это разве не ошибка той штуки, которая запускается через `cmd`, при чём тут запускающий её питоновский скрипт? Покажите **полный стек-трейс ошибки**.

Comment: Посоветовал бы сначала htop'ом посмотреть что это может быть.
Была похожая проблема, в тп ничего толкового не ответили, пришлось провайдера поменять и все исправилось.

Comment: Ну то есть вопрос вообще не про питон, получается в данный момент

Comment: Дак самое интересное то, что раньше скрипт этот отрабатывал нормально...